# static network connection between two debians

Tags: debian, static-ip, static-routes

I am having a big trouble in setting a simple static connection between two computers (two Debians, say A and B). I know, in principle, how to do it, and have done properly for computers B and C (all Debians). However, configuring A is the main goal. Whenever I connect A to my home router from my internet provider, the Network Manager finds connection perfectly fine, thus I know that Ethernet card is fine. I believe that this means that drivers are ok too. Below are the outputs of some commands. What I find odd (among other things) is that the "Supported ports" in ethtool doesn't show anything when plugging A to B (although it shows TP when connected directed to internet router). I didn't find such a case when looking on the web.

Does anyone have some suggestion or hint? I am fighting against this for months, and have already tried several hints from tutorials, forums, debian pages... I am considering installing cent OS and see if it is easier.

Thanks for any idea in advance.

```
$ update-rc.d -f dhcpd remove  # I have disabled dhcp, not sure if it is needed
$ systemctl disable NetworkManager.service  # also disabled the network manager


$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


#auto enp2s0
allow-hotplug enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
  address 192.168.10.101
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.169.10.100


$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.169.10.100


$ ip a show eno1:

2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:10:32:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.101/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip route show
default via 192.168.10.100 dev eno1 onlink linkdown 
192.168.10.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.101 linkdown 


$ ethtool eno1

Settings for eno1:
    Supported ports: [ ]
    Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Port: Other
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x0000000f (15)
                   drv probe link timer
    Link detected: no


$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And on my computer B:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


#auto enp2s0
allow-hotplug enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
  address 192.168.10.100
  netmask 255.255.255.0

$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward  # I have enabled ip forwarding
1
```

Finally, at A, if plugged directly to the Internet router:

```
Settings for eno1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x0000000f (15)
                   drv probe link timer
    Link detected: yes
```

Comment: *"Static connection"* -- ???  Do you mean an *ad hoc* connection using static IP addresses?

Comment: Yes. I mean, two computers connected directly by an Ethernet cable, both configured with static IP addresses, say by editing network/interfaces